# Match Column and Line in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, multiple-columns

Input File-test1

```
Failed ,abc,  /clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008, Windows File System
Failed ,abc, /clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008 ,Windows File System
Completed, abc /clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008, Windows File System
Failed ,def ,/clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008 ,Windows File System
Failed ,def ,/clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008 ,Windows File System
Failed ,def ,/clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008 ,Windows File System
Failed ,ghi  ,/clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008, Windows File System
Failed ,jkl ,/clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008 ,Windows File System
Completed ,def ,/clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008, Windows File System
Completed ,hkm ,/clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008 Windows File System
```

Expected Output

```
Failed ghi,  /clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008, Windows File System
Failed jkl, /clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008, Windows File System
```

Code

```
sed -n '/Completed/ s,\(.*\) .* Completed$,\1,a' "$pwd"/test1 | grep -v -f - "$pwd"/test1
```

I want to get the column that has only Failed values or they haven't got completed in any of the rows.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "we'll do your homework for you" site.
Show your effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors you need help with

Comment: sed -n '/Completed/ s,(.) . Completed$,\1,a' "$pwd"/test1 | grep -v -f - "$pwd"/test1                                 This is i have done and its working for earlier other file but not for this..

Comment: Edit your question. Do not add additional clarifications within the comments....

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `awk` is your option, would you please try:

```
awk '
/^Failed/ {gsub(/,/, "", $2); fail[$2]=$0}         # if failed, store the line
/^Completed/ {gsub(/,/, "", $2); delete fail[$2]}  # if completed, abandon the line from the list
END {for (i in fail) print fail[i]}     # finally print the remaining list
' file
```

Output:

```
Failed jkl ,/clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008 ,Windows File System
Failed ghi ,/clients/FORD_1030PM_EST_Windows2008, Windows File System
```

Comment: If text in File is separated with comma instead of space then it's not working. else its working fine. I tried using awk -F, ' ' but it's still not working

Comment: I've updated the script considering the case the field separator contains a comma. Btw it is not recommended to change your question after someone has posted an answer based on the original question. BR.

Comment: My pleasure. Cheers.